# Menu active trail not working with facets

Tags: 8, navigation, search

I'm using Facets and Facets API Pretty Path (https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_pretty_paths), together with Menu Trail By Path (https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path). Thanks to Pretty Path I have normal paths without query strings. when I click on a menu item it goes to the correct page but the active trail isn't set in the main menu.

Only when I clear the cache the active trail is set correctly.

At first I blamed the query strings but even without query string the active trail isn't working like it should.

At this point I'm not sure how to continue, I've debugged the Menu trail by Path module and everything works as it should. Perhaps a double caching issue? Any thoughts?

Comment: This is tagged as Drupal 8. Do you mean Drupal 7 as it looks like facetapi_pretty_paths is not available to D8.